# Reusable content in List without Publishing Feature?

Tags: reusable

I was wondering if there's a way to use the reusable content without turning on the Publishing features? I have a list with the Publishing HTML field but the reusable content button is not displaying. I don't want to use publishing feature as it prevents the Save Site as Template option.

Thank you,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

The contenttypes for Reusable content is defined in the feature PublishingResources, the Ribbon button in the feature Publishing, so I don't think you'll have any luck adding it without the full Publishing.

And even if you did, you might run into problems as the Id of the list is stored in a Web.property "_ReusableContentListId" which wouldn't be updated on save as template + create new site.